# Generate numbers between two ranges - python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, range

I am trying to create numpy array contains values (positive or negative) and works with float type between x and y with step (start, stop, step ).

I did the code it works, but I it is not effective because of the length of the number range more than what it should be.

```
In loop --- the right length --- what I get
0             4                    4
1             16                   16
2             64                   64
3             256 **               289 **
4             1024                 1024
5             4096                 4096
6             16384 **             16641 **
7             65536                65536
```

you can see the difference between what should I get and what I get

Please see the code I did, it will give a good I idea about the problem:

```
from itertools import product
import math
import random
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)


start = -5.12
stop = 5.12

dimension = 2

level =1
loop= 10

the_right_size = (2**level)**dimension

# here we creat a step to move from start to stop beasd on the step.
step = (1/((2**level)-1))*(stop-start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range (loop):

        step = (1/((2**level)-1))*(stop-start)
        the_right_size = (2**level)**dimension

        number_range = [j for j in product(np.arange(start, stop+step, step), repeat=dimension)]
        number_range = np.array(number_range)

        print ("number range lenght", (len(number_range)))

        print("the_right_size", the_right_size)
        level = level +1
```

This was fiexd by changing this line:

```
number_range = [j for j in product(np.arange(start, stop+step, step), repeat=dimension)]
```

to

```
number_range = [j for j in product(np.arange(start, stop+step/2, step), repeat=dimension)]
```

But I believe this wrong way and not effective, any advice or help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about list comprehension in a range `[base**x for x in range(1, 8+1)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encountered a common problem of float arithmetic. In a binary system, not every number can be represented. [See for instance here for more information.](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
The first hint that this happens lies already in your numbers: For n=3 you get 17² instead of 16² and for n=6 129² instead of 128². Something goes wrong in your line containing

```
np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
```

and the reason is that you calculate step in advance. Usually you calculate the right amount of data points with `np.arange`, but due to float point inaccuracies, you have sometimes an additional point after your `stop` value. 
To overcome this problem, you could rewrite this line to

```
number_range = np.array(list(product(np.arange(start, stop + 0.0001, step), repeat=dimension)))
```

0.0001 could be any small number that is smaller than your smallest `step` value. But this is not optimal - what if `step` becomes really small? You came up with another solution by halving `step` in your calculation, which gave you the right number of data points.
But why not let numpy deal with all this implementation details and use [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) in this situation?

```
number_range = np.array(list(product(np.linspace(start, stop, 2 ** level), repeat=dimension)))
```

`step` is here the number of points between start and stop and numpy takes care of the calculation. Problem solved.
You might have noticed that I also substituted your

```
[j for j in product(...)]
```

with

```
list(product(...))
```

because they are equivalent. There are things you can optimise in your code, maybe you want to discuss this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).